# OCR for business card reader in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ocr

I was incorporating the OCR in my iPhone app using open source library "tesseract".I have seen some apps on AppStore doing so. I am just wondering how can I segregate the data that it reads from the card, i.e, how will I distinguish between say FirstName and the LastName or between CompanyName and the person's name, how will I distinguish whether the number is Phone# or the Fax# etc.

I wish that there are some standard formats of the Business Cards but I feel that would be hard luck to assume so.Any inkling on that would help a lot.

I posted it over here to gather the thoughts of various developers so that I can come up with some good logic (to make it more accurate) to classify the data that we get from the OCR engine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [OCR scanning, compare converted text in iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992476/ocr-scanning-compare-converted-text-in-iphone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Create some guesses how the various text pieces could be interpreted and let the user pick the best one. The format should be pretty standard per country (e.g. in English/German/French etc., the first name is 99.9% in front of the last name)
- If now guess is good enough, the user can assign the fields himself
- For the firstname/lastname problem, you could maybe consult a local file or web service with common pre-parsed names in the user's country

Comment: Thanks a lot.User controllable selection would be good.Will consider your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

In order to distinguish the First Name, Last Name, Company Name, Fax or a Phone number use "Regular Expressions".

Example:

Phone - "^(\s*\d\s*){12}$"
Email - "^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$"

In the same way,  you can find the regular expressions for other Labels in the below link.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-regular-expressions/

Thank You.

Comment: Hi [@Naveen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9930993), thanks for your input. This answer was pulled automatically for review and the review was assigned to me. I recommend adding more details to this answer to more closely address the question OR removing it and making it a comment to the question. Otherwise you might get down-voted since it’s not so useful to the questioner and any viewers.

Comment: Thanks bro, you saved my life 